# Форма обратной связи в модальном окне при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, есть блок, в котором присутствует форма обратной связи[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При уменьшении экрана до 480px эта форма скрывает и появляется кнопка "Заказать доставку".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку в модальном окне появлялась эта же форма

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo
Нужно задать кнопке соответствующий `data-target="#myModal"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общий ответ без примера: продублировать форму в футер и поднимать ее через js по клику в модальном окне.

Answer (score 0):

При нужном разрешении отображайте модальное, а кнопку скрывайте:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom-m {
    display: block!important;
  }
  
  .custom-btn {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg custom-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal custom-m" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```